# Como adicionar os arquivos no .gitignore no Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, git

Em algum momento do nosso projeto, foram enviados os arquivos de configurações locais (`workspace.xml`, `app.iml`) para o *git*. Dentre esse arquivos, alguns do próprio *gradle* (`cache.properties.lock`, `fileHashes.bin`, `fileSnapshots.bin`, `outputFileStates.bin`, `taskArtifacts.bin`).

Acredito que esses arquivos estavam no `.gitignore`, mas não consigo recolocá-los, sendo que agora a cada `pull` esses mesmos arquivos dão conflitos, porque são configurações alteradas pela IDE localmente.

Como posso adicioná-los novamente? Todos devem estar no `.gitignore`?

Comment: Nao percebi a intencao. Queres retira-los do source control?

Comment: Isso mesmo, como esses arquivos são gerados por cada programador em sua IDE, não precisamos enviá-las para o git, evitando conflitos a cada pull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já deves saber, precisas de adicionar esses arquivos ao .gitignore.

Mas o gitignore só serve para ignorar arquivos que não estão em source control (de modo a continuarem a não ser versionados). Se eles já estão a ser versionados (ou *tracked*), então precisas de os apagar localmente, e fazer um commit com essas eliminações. Depois disso, podes restaurá-los, e eles vão ser ignorados pelo Git.

Resumindo:

- faz um backup dos ficheiros noutra pasta qualquer
- apaga-os do projecto
- faz commit com essas remoções
- restaura os ficheiros

Comment: Isso funcionou para mim, Obrigado!